# 404 on content area in admin module

Tags: admin

I am getting

> 404 Error
>
> Page not found

in the main content area of my admin module. Both the header and footers are displayed, but im left with a white screen between, with no other information than what ive posted.

In var/log/admin.log

> 2013-09-11T08:33:34+00:00 INFO (6): myname /admin/controller/action/
> 2013-09-11T08:33:34+00:00 INFO (6): myname /admin/controller/action/

The action that it is trying to access is

```
public function newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('*/*/edit');
}
```

The layout file node maps to that edit controllerAction. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Logout and in, looks like the new ACL is not loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that has not worked

Answer (score 1):

If Logout and log back in again does not solve your 404 page not found error then try changing -

```
$this->_redirect() instead of _forward
```

Just for debugging you can comment redirection & try to print something from newAction() if it works then there might be redirection problem.

Comment: From using this method I was able to echo out text from my block, so found that was working. It turns out I had not extended my Tabs.php file, once sorting that the page showed as expected  and I was able to return to _forward